# Future of pigpio library - alive or dead?

Tags: pigpio, update, pi-5

Can anyone verify that there will NOT be an update for the pigpio library to work with Pi V5? ( Please, not a guess or opinion).

I have used the pigpio library extensively on my projects, Pi Zero through V4 Pi.  What a shame it will be if all of the hard work that went into this great library would be lost!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Future of GPIO access on Pi5](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145013/future-of-gpio-access-on-pi5)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did see that topic already and "Joan" stated that it will not work, but no evidence of any followup work to be done on pigpio library.  I think the answer is "no".

Comment: You will not get a more definitive answer than from the author of pigpio.

Comment: I agree - it **is** a shame - just as it is that `WiringPi` has now fallen into deprecation. The  *thing*  that bothers me about these events is that (apparently) they were both brought on by changes to the Linux kernel; i.e. a *"top down"* (forced) change from above. OTOH, I suppose the "kernel people" must look out for their own interests, but it's not clear to me that the situation demanded that these changes be done in a fashion that excluded other (wiringpi & pigpio) approaches. But I simply do not know enough about the kernel to say.

Comment: I was surprised about the lack of software support for the new I/O hardware.  In my working career of factory automation,  when a vendor of control hardware came out with a product, there was associated software, libraries, IDE, etc .  If you think about it, you know that the team that worked on the new chip had to have software to test it, so somewhere there exists snippets of code that would prove to be useful ( Hint, hint to the Raspberry Pi org ).  I can only dream!

Answer (score 1):

As Milliways suggests the answer is probably no.

The key features of pigpio are the efficient sampling of GPIO at high rates and the efficient generation of hardware timed PWM on all GPIO.  I don't see how these features could be provided by the new RP1 based GPIO.

However for many years now Guy McSwain has been the maintainer of pigpio.  He may have a different view.

Comment: It occurred to me that it may be possible to write a kernel module which provides efficient access. There is a PWM kernel module which works on existing Pi - if ever I manage to get a Pi5 I intend to test and reverse engineer.

Comment: Don't know how I might help, but I'm available. Electrical Engineer-retired, long time 'C' programmer, embedded too.

Comment: @Milliways What pigpio provides could and probably should be provided by a kernel system.  Unfortunately while I might have that vision I do not have kernel experience.

Comment: @Milliways: Why do think you need an RPi 5 to test that? Also, wrt writing a kernel module, you will be interested in a passage from the kernel documentation on GPIO: [`Do not under any circumstances abuse the GPIO userspace ABI to cut corners in any product development projects. If you use it for prototyping, then do not productify the prototype: rewrite it using proper kernel drivers.`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/using-gpio.html)