# How do I get pigpiod to work on bookworm?

Tags: pigpio, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

In previous versions of the OS, I would turn on Remote GPIO from Preferences->Interfaces and then run the following:

```
sudo systemctl enable pigpiod
sudo systemctl start pigpiod
```

Then running

```
pigs t
```

would give me some output.  On a Raspberry Pi running bookworm, I get an error:

> socket connect failed

How do I get pigpoid to work on bookworm?  I read somewhere that it may be an issue with incorrect resolution of localhost, but my hosts file seems to be correct in that it has the line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Future of GPIO access on Pi5](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145013/future-of-gpio-access-on-pi5)

Comment: NOTE pigpiod works on Bookworm - just not on Pi5. It is unchanged on my Pi4.